# Equipment is now Gear

Tags: discussion, tags, announcement

This is a simple fact of search frequency.  A quick check on google trends shows that people do search for hiking gear, camping gear, etc.  However equipment does not show up in these searches often, if at all.

I was the originator of the synonym, but looking at google -- this was a mistake.

I'm posting this so that people can know it happened.